# Undefined links in component pdf; resolved at pdfpages compile time

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdfpages

I am trying something ambitious and I hope there is a way to get it to work.

I have a number of pdf documents that I will eventually pull together in one pdf. One of the documents, a cover page of sorts, to include links to other components in the final pdf.

To do this, I set up three dummy documents:

```
% doc1
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the first document.
\end{document}
```

---

```
% doc2
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the second document.
\end{document}
```

---

```
% doc3
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the third document.
\end{document}
```

---

Then, I construct the coverpage document:

```
% coverpage
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is the link to the first document, \ref{doc1.1}.

Here is the link to the second document, \ref{doc2.1}.

Here is the link to the third documents, \ref{doc3.1}.

\end{document}
```

---

And finally, I construct the wrapper document, which calls all the component pdfs, and defines the links:

```
% main document
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Document set}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

\includepdf[link=true]{coverpage.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc1]{doc1.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc2]{doc2.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc3]{doc3.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I want the references in coverpage to show up when compiled within `main.tex`. Obviously, the references I want in the `coverpage.tex` file live in the `main.aux` file. I am wondering if there is a way to streamline this process so that it works, or indeed if there is an easier way to do this.

I want to write the coverpage separately instead of within the main document, since it uses its own documentclass which is not how I want the main document to be typeset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulties are:

- When PDF pages are included, the annotations (links) are lost.
- Even, if they would not be lost, the problem remains, how the inter document links should be converted to inner document links.

The following example uses the positioning tracking feature of pdfTeX/LuaTeX or XeTeX.
The procedure is as follows.

First the document `coverpage` does not set any links, but instead of the links it saves the position of the link text in the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}

\newcommand*{\sref}[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#2}%
    \raisebox{-\dp0}{\zsavepos{#1-a}}%
    \usebox0%
    \raisebox{\ht0}{\zsavepos{#1-b}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
Here is the link to the \sref{doc1}{first document}.

Here is the link to the \sref{doc2}{second document}.

Here is the link to the \sref{doc3}{third document}.

\end{document}
```

The first argument of `\sref` is the link handle/label name, the second the link text that appears on the page.

Package `zref-savepos` is a wrapper for the `\pdfsavepos` feature. The positions are numbers with implicit unit `sp`. The origin is the lower left corner. The `.aux` file contains:

```
\relax 
\providecommand\zref@newlabel[2]{}
\zref@newlabel{doc1-a}{\posx{15751804}\posy{46450400}}
\zref@newlabel{doc1-b}{\posx{19907887}\posy{46905511}}
\zref@newlabel{doc2-a}{\posx{15751804}\posy{45663968}}
\zref@newlabel{doc2-b}{\posx{20670654}\posy{46119079}}
\zref@newlabel{doc3-a}{\posx{15751804}\posy{44877536}}
\zref@newlabel{doc3-b}{\posx{20195519}\posy{45332647}}
```

The main document reads the data in the `.aux` file using package `zref-xr`. The label names are prefixed with `cover-` to avoid name clashes:

```
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zexternaldocument[cover-]{coverpage}
```

Then the `coverpage` is included with options `fitpaper` and `picturecommand`. The first ensures that the included page is not scaled with some unknown scaling factor that invalidates the positions. Make sure that `coverpage.tex` and `main.tex` are using the same paper size and secondly the output driver needs to be notified, because this is not done by LaTeX. I have used paper size A4 and `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` for `coverpage.tex`. Option `pass` does not change the current geometry and the package notifies the output driver (pdfTeX) about the paper size.

Option `picturecommand=\coverlinks` calls macro `\coverlinks` that sets the links at the right positions using the imported position labels. The link text itself is just an empty box with the right size using invisible rules.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-xr,zref-savepos}
\zexternaldocument[cover-]{coverpage}
\newcommand*{\coverlinks}{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1sp}%
  \coverlink{doc1}%
  \coverlink{doc2}%
  \coverlink{doc3}%
}
\newcommand*{\coverlink}[1]{%
  \put(\zposx{cover-#1-a},\zposy{cover-#1-a}){%
    \makebox(0,0)[lb]{%
      \hyperlink{#1.1}{%
        \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\zposy{cover-#1-b}sp-\zposy{cover-#1-a}sp}%
        \rule{\dimexpr\zposx{cover-#1-b}sp-\zposx{cover-#1-a}sp}{0pt}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\title{Document set}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

\includepdf[fitpaper,link=true,picturecommand=\coverlinks]{coverpage.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc1]{doc1.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc2]{doc2.pdf}
\includepdf[link=true, linkname=doc3]{doc3.pdf}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Main document with links on coverpage]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try out your solution, but major props for your effort.